# arithmetic operations between files

Tags: text-processing, arithmetic

Say I have these two input files:

```
> file1
2
3
4

> file2
10
100
1000
```

And I would like to compute: file1/file2 for each line, resulting in file3:

```
> file 3
0.2
0.03
0.004
```

Divisions in bash can be achieved by: `$((file1_line/file2_line))`

Comment: What's the exact question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `paste` and `bc` combination is a good choice for simple arithmetic:

```
paste -d/ file1 file2 | bc -l
```

Output:

```
.2000000000
.0300000000
.0040000000
```

#### A more advanced example

With some trickery you can get a bit more complicated. Say `file3` contains:

```
6
7
8
```

You can do `(file1 + file3) / file2` like this:

```
paste -d'(+)/' /dev/null file1 file3 /dev/null file2
```

Output:

```
(2+6)/10
(3+7)/100
(4+8)/1000
```

This works because `paste` cycles through its delimiter list for each line.

#### React to divide-by-zero

Illigal operations sent to `bc` result in a warning being sent to standard error. You could redirect these to a different file and decide program flow based on its content, e.g.:

```
paste -d/ file1 file2 | bc -l > resultfile 2> errorfile
if grep -q 'Divide by zero' errorfile; then
  echo "Error in calculation"
else
  echo "All is well"
fi
```

Or if there was any error:

```
paste -d/ file1 file2 | bc -l > resultfile 2> errorfile
if ! file errorfile | grep -q empty; then
  echo "Error in calculation"
else
  echo "All is well"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @Thor. Do you think it is possible to integrate an exit/skip status for any division by zero? As in: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28016/ignore-or-catch-division-by-zero

Comment: @dovah: `bc` gives you a divide-by-zero warning, so it should be straightforward to integrate. It just depends on what you mean by that

Comment: @dovah: Added a divide-by-zero example

Answer (score 7):

start with

```
 paste file1 file2 | awk '{printf "%f\n",$1/$2 } '
```

where

- `paste` will "merge" file
- `awk` will compute division, one at a time.

if you don't like too many trailling 0's, just add

```
... | sed -e s/0*\$//
```

to exit in case of `0`

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '!$2 {exit ; }  {printf "%f\n",$1/$2 } '
```

Comment: With **awk** you needn't **paste** `awk '{getline a <"file2";print $1/a}' file1`